# Save All Files Before Build Gone in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

In Visual Studio 2010, there was a setting under Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build And Run --> Before Building (Save all changes).  In VS 2012, this setting appears to be gone, and my solution is not saving before build.  Note that the projects I am building is a MakeFile project with Clang/LLVM for the compiler, if that is relevant info.

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: Which edition of VS are you using?

Comment: I am using VS 2010 Pro, but I believe many of our developers are using VS 2012 Express.

Comment: I looked and I couldn't see the option in VS 2012 Pro either :(

Comment: As a result, I regularly commit only part of a change, because it passed tests in VS but didn't get saved to disk. :-(

Comment: I'm using VS2012 update 4. It doesn't have that setting either, but it does save changes before building (tested with a C# project). It seems to me that the option *not* to save was removed, and not the option to save.

Answer (score 4):

According to the answer provided by Vicky Song (Microsoft), the feature is no longer available.  If you wish to submit a feature request, they will consider it.

Reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/be441ff6-682f-4534-b653-99632a7975a4/before-building-settings

Answer (score 0):

This feature is very useful mainly when considering that many users have the Visual Studio to crash randomly (myself as well). So when I want to run a compile-build-test, I would like to save everything open (including the environment that gets lost on those nasty events)...