# Disable auto save of code in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Pro for windows software development. Earlier I used to use VS 2008.

One option that I couldn't find (which was there in older version) is :

Before building - 
 -Do not save any changes 
 -Save all changes 
 -Prompt to save changes

The above was available in Tools->Options->Build & Run in older versions.

At times when I make temp changes in my code which I don't want to save it then that feature comes in handy.

Is there any way I can stop VS 2012 from saving my code before I build/run it.

Thank you,

Cheers,
GR

Comment: That's a removed option that 4 million programmers never noticed.  You're alone.  You could run msbuild from the VS command prompt.

Comment: What should you do if you are making temp changes in your program that you don't want to save ?

Comment: 3,999,999. You're not alone.

Comment: Please vote this suggestion on VisualStudio UserVoice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8492068-do-not-save-any-changes-before-building

Comment: @Hans Passant You'd have to be a fool to speak for "4 million programmers"
This is an excellent question and having this feature is actually very important to some people

Comment: I'll gladly wear that tin foil hat.  Talk to @Walt, he's taken it upon himself to deliver the news.  Courageous guy.

Answer (score 2):

That feature was dropped in Visual Studio 2010.  As far as I know it hasn't resurfaced in Visual Studio 2012.

[Save All Files Before Build Gone in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304989/save-all-files-before-build-gone-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately if I am testing my program by making some changes in code which I don't want to save then I am stuck.

Comment: That's why people use Source control.

Comment: It's bad idea to use source control for saving some temp code to test another version of temp code... There is an IDE's local history for this.

Comment: This feature was NOT dropped in Visual Studio 2010. I am using VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE prompts for saving on unsaved code or resources when you close the project.

With GIT or other source control you can run on command to save versions.
I actually like the program "Second Copy" which you can set up to save versions of your code (I save the last 15 versions of any changed file in the project). This is set up to run whenever a file changes, but you would not want it to save a new version every time you make a change while testing/debugging, preferring to only back up to the new version every time the file is SAVED either manually using the mouse/Shortcut keys or upon close of the IDE. That way you have true backup of code you are satisfied with.

I think having autosave is dangerous because it overworks the source control if you have one in place (either GIT or Second Copy or whatever) and if you don't you lose the ability to go back to a prior version should you stuff up the code or decide not to proceed with changes. Having the option, though, to have autosave (either at intervals or on "Run"/"Build") should still be there to please all users (but the default should be "off")
Of course on "Publish" all files are saved anyway (as they should be).

Give "Second Copy" consideration...http://www.secondcopy.com/ (I have no association with second copy, I have just used it for years and love it)

Comment: I still missing the settings which Microsoft removed after VS 2010