# Can I force Visual Studio (2010) to do a "Save All" when I build my solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, git-extensions

I have a recurring frustration with Visual Studio 2010. I'll add a new file to a project, build, run tests - all good. Then I'll commit and push my changes (I'm using GitExtensions and GitHub)

Finally, I'll exit Visual Studio - and get asked if I want to save changes to MyProject.csproj. Sure enough, after saving changes, the .csproj file now shows local modifications in GitExtensions - which means the previous commit/push actually pushed broken code, because I'd pushed the new file without the corresponding .csproj file reference. All because Visual Studio doesn't actually save your `.csproj` file when you add new files to your project - although it seems to compile it quite happily without your changes being saved to disk yet...

Is there any way I can force Visual Studio to do a "save all" whenever I add a new file - or whenever I run some frequent command, like building the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Look under `Tools` --> `Options` --> `Projects and Solutions` --> `Build And Run` --> `Before Building (Save all changes)` for the option.

[image]

Later versions of VS (2012+) should always save your projects when building.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not possible post-2010. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304989/save-all-files-before-build-gone-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Actually, the option to configure the setting has been removed, @Jeroen. Later versions of Visual Studio *always* save before building. It is indeed frustrating to be unable to turn that option off, but in this case, the asker gets the behavior he desires.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yeah, I probably should've worded my comment differently. I wasn't entirely sure about it since I've had some issues with an unsaved .csproj file before but I might just not have built the project that time.

Comment: My VS 2017 installation is not saving on build, and as pointed out this option does not exist post 2010. Has anyone else encountered that?