# Visual Studio 2013 .csproj not automatically saving

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, csproj

We have come across a problem where our `.csproj` file does not save until we do `Save All`. This is causing issues as it is often not pulled into git and send up having missing file errors when trying to build. I know that in VS <s>2013</s> 2012+, the `.csproj` file is supposed to save whenever a build occurs. Publishing causes a build to take place so there is no reason for it not to save.

Comment: I think this is the default behavior since the beginning day of VS.

Comment: @davidshen84 I will refer you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250202/can-i-force-visual-studio-2010-to-do-a-save-all-when-i-build-my-solution).

The answer states that starting from VS 2012, it will always save. The dropdown menu that he presented isn't even present in these recent versions.

Comment: They removed that drop down, does not mean they make it default...

Comment: Not having .csproj file updated automatically on save is the source of many bugs in our dev group. Always have to remember to hit "Ctrl+Shift+S". Hope this will be fixed in future versions of VS.

Comment: I even changed my hotkey to bind "Ctrl+S" to "Save all"

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in VS2019. If you can, please [report a problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and we'll get it fixed.