# Save all files from command line

Tags: c#, file, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Is it possible to force `Visual Studio` to save all files from the command line?
I'm using `msbuild.exe` in order to build and publish my solution but I would also like to save all changes in the files before that.
I've tried using `msbuild.exe`, `csc.exe` and `devenv.exe` but none of them gives the option to save.

Comment: You mean save all the changes in files that are currently open in Visual Studio?

Comment: @haim770 yes I do

Comment: is this what you need? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/10/31/save-changes-before-building/

Comment: @Fuzzybear can't find this option, unfortunately it's only availabe in VS2008, 2010

Comment: @Yoav what version of  VS are u running?

Comment: 2013, I edited my question and added the tag

Comment: It looks like Microsoft removed that feeature from VS2012 and upwards yes, from this thread people were having issues getting the files NOT to save on build. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be441ff6-682f-4534-b653-99632a7975a4/before-building-settings?forum=vssetup

Comment: also just found this similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304989/save-all-files-before-build-gone-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: It saves when building from within VS, not when build from the command line

Comment: This isn't trivial: a command line is a seperate process so it doesn't know anything at all about possibly running instances of another process (VS). Though you can probably hack together an application which lists open VS windows and sends Ctrl-Shift-S to them but that seems just too much work. Somewhat less work would be to inverse the principle and invoke msbuild from within VS, e.g. the publishing as a post-build event.

Comment: @stijn decided that for now I'll go with your first suggestion. it isn't ideal but it works

Answer (score 1):

This isn't ideal but the following does the trick (for all open instances of visual studio):

```
Process []vsProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");
foreach (var item in vsProcesses)
{
    IntPtr h = item.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    SendKeys.SendWait("^+s");
}
```

I'll keep looking for a better approach but for now it'll do.